# Render 3D Object(from Blender) with dynamic text after clicking element in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, blender

I am working on threejs library and I am stuck in a position. I've created a scene in which some mountains and rocks will be there. I've set click event listeners using rayCaster in threejs.
Here is the working [demo](https://codepen.io/abibv/pen/mdVNrmo)

```
function createLabel(text, x, y, z, size, color) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.font = size + "pt Arial";

  var margin = 10;
  var textWidth = context.measureText(text).width;

  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.strokeStyle = "red";
  context.strokeRect(canvas.width / 2 - textWidth / 2 - margin / 2, canvas.height / 2 - size / 2 - +margin / 2, textWidth + margin, size + margin);

  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  var texture = new THREE.canvasTexture(canvas);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map : texture
  });

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas.width, canvas.height, 10, 10), material);
  mesh.overdraw = true;
  mesh.position.x = x - canvas.width / 2;
  mesh.position.y = y - canvas.height / 2;
  return mesh;
}
```

Now, When I click any element(diamonds or mountains) on the page, a new 3d object must be rendered with dynamic text on its face, (texture as material) from server.

I've searched along and tried different things such as canvasTexture, TextGeometry,... But I couldn't get that.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You say you want to add a new 3D cube at the click-point, but you are adding a new `PlaneGeometry`. Which is correct? Depending on how you constructed your scene, the plane could be "on-edge" to the camera, and thereby not visible.

Comment: Actually, I need a custom  3D object to be rendered in the scene. But for the sake of simulating my environment in CodePen, I've used PlaneGeometry (instead of BoxGeometry by mistake). But even in PlaneGoemetry also, I couldn't render the PlaneGeometry with Text...
I've edited my question.